# Adding and new record of data to a table from a toggle button click

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to create an audit trail for a form I've created that records when users ran certain operations on this form.

The form is called "Jobs" and it has a number of toggle switches on it.

When the user clicks a toggle switch on/off I want to automatically record some information in a table called "History".

The table "History" will have the following fields:

- **HistoryId** (primary key; autonumber)
- **JobId** (will bring this across as the foreign key from the current record in "Jobs" form)
- **UserName** (will get this with `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`)
- **DateClicked** (will get this with `Now()`)
- **ToggleButtonName** (will get get this with the `.Caption` property of the toggle button)
- **ToggleOnOff** (will get this with the `.Value` property of the toggle button)

Below is some test code I've tried.

For test purposes I've only populated the **JobID** foreign key field in the History table and have created a field **HistoryDesc** just to see if I can get some other values in to the record.

Note that I'm using the field **Ad_PerfChecks** in the "Jobs" table to store the toggle status of the **togAd_PerfChecks** toggle button for later.

```vb
Public Sub RefreshSubData()

    tblHistory_sub.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

---

```vb
Private Sub togAd_PerfChecks_Click()

    If Me.Ad_PerfChecks = 0 Or IsNull(Me.Ad_PerfChecks) Then

        Dim rs1 As Recordset
        Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHistory")

        rs1.AddNew
        rs1!JobID = Me.JobID
        rs1!HistoryDesc = "Ad_PerfChecks was turned ON"
        rs1.Update

        Set rs1 = Nothing

        RefreshSubData

        Me.togAd_PerfChecks.Value = True
        Me.togAd_PerfChecks.PressedColor = RGB(34, 177, 76)
        Me.Ad_PerfChecks = 1

    ElseIf Me.Ad_PerfChecks = 1 Then

        Dim rs2 As Recordset
        Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHistory")

        rs2.AddNew
        rs2!JobID = Me.JobID
        rs2!HistoryDesc = "Ad_PerfChecks was turned OFF"
        rs2.Update

        Set rs2 = Nothing

        RefreshSubData

        Me.togAd_PerfChecks.Value = False
        Me.togAd_PerfChecks.BackColor = RGB(36, 36, 36)
        Me.Ad_PerfChecks = 0

    End If

End Sub
```

For the most part this is working ok, except the first click creates a record in the "History" table without the JobId foreign key for some reason. After that every click creates a new record with the data I want.

Here's an example output in the "History" table when clicking the toggle button 4 times:

```
| HistoryId | JobId |           History Desc           |
|     1     |       |     Ad_PerfChecks was turned ON  |
|     2     |   1   |     Ad_PerfChecks was turned OFF |
|     3     |   1   |     Ad_PerfChecks was turned ON  |
|     4     |   1   |     Ad_PerfChecks was turned OFF |
```

Any ideas how to ensure the first click gets the JobID foreign key? Also let me know if there's a better approach to this.. kinda getting to the edges of my VBA knowledge here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer this myself.. In my test data I have code that updates the Jobs record ***after*** the History records are added, hence the Jobs record hasn't finished updating and I assume hasn't received its autonumber yet.

Moving the code around as follows seemed to fix the issue:

```vb
Private Sub togAd_PerfChecks_Click()

    If Me.Ad_PerfChecks = 0 Or IsNull(Me.Ad_PerfChecks) Then

        Me.togAd_PerfChecks.Value = True
        Me.togAd_PerfChecks.PressedColor = RGB(34, 177, 76)
        Me.Ad_PerfChecks = 1

        Dim rs1 As Recordset
        Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHistory")

        rs1.AddNew
        rs1!JobID = Me.JobID
        rs1!HistoryDesc = "Ad_PerfChecks was turned ON"
        rs1.Update

        Set rs1 = Nothing

        RefreshSubData

    ElseIf Me.Ad_PerfChecks = 1 Then

        Me.togAd_PerfChecks.Value = False
        Me.togAd_PerfChecks.BackColor = RGB(36, 36, 36)
        Me.Ad_PerfChecks = 0

        Dim rs2 As Recordset
        Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHistory")

        rs2.AddNew
        rs2!JobID = Me.JobID
        rs2!HistoryDesc = "Ad_PerfChecks was turned OFF"
        rs2.Update

        Set rs2 = Nothing

        RefreshSubData

    End If

End Sub
```